# Validation Message CSS alignment in ASP MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP MVC,CSS and html. 
Here is what i want to do:
1. Right after an Editorfor("Type" filed in my example), i need a button to display all available options in the database. I have already achieved this by using JQuery UI autocomplete.
2. Validation on this required field. I need to display validation message below the editor box. My code is not working.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TestType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TestType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                <button id="ShowAllType" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" title="Show all existing test types">
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TestType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>     
    </div>
```

Here is before post.

[image]

Here is after post.
[image]

As the picture shows, "Description" field is OK. I need help to fix the alignment on "Type" field to display same as Description field. Thanks in advance.

Add CSS and JS:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>

<style>
    .ui-autocomplete-loading {
        background: white url("../images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif") right center no-repeat;
    }

    .ui-autocomplete {
        max-height: 300px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
        overflow-x: hidden;
        /* add padding to account for vertical scrollbar */
        padding-right: 20px;
    }

    #ShowAllType {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin-left: -1px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #TestType {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .required:after 
    {
        content: "*";
        font-weight: bold;
        color: red;
        vertical-align:sub; 
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">




    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#TestType").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    //url: "/EndEffectors/AutoCompleteType",
                    url: "@Url.Action("AutoCompleteType", "EndEffectors")",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { Prefix: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#TestType").removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");
                        response(data);
                    }
                })
            },
            complete: function () {
                $("#TestType").removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading")
            },
            minLength: 0,
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        });



        $("#ShowAllType").on("click", function () {

            $("#TestType").autocomplete("search", "");
            return false;
        });


    }
    )
</script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Edit 2: I tried add `<br/>` after the button, here is the result. Button size is not right.

[image]

Comment: usually the error message would be in a span with a class of `field-validation-error` so you could try making it block so it will always drop down onto the next line: `.field-validation-error { display:block; }`.  You may also need to clear left or both as it looks like something is being floated, but without seeing your styles and rendered html, this is all just a guess

Comment: Hello Pete, i have added the CSS and JS. Can you take a look? Thanks.

Comment: Might be frowned upon, by why not just put a `<br/>` element below the `button` element?

Comment: Hello BviLLe, I tried add br, please see my update image.

Comment: wrap your editor for and button in a separate div and make it position:relative, then put the validation for below that new div wrapper

Comment: Thank you very much Pete! It worked!